# maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin with Hibernate 4.3.5, Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, glassfish

I have a problem with using maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin (version 3.1.1) with Hibernate 4.3.5 and Spring.

My pom.xml looks like that:

```
<dependencies> 
    ...   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My Spring's entityManagerFactory configuration is quite standard:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="hibernateJpaProperties"/>
</bean>
```

When I invoke `mvn embedded-glassfish:run`, I get an exception:

> SEVERE: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-persistence.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey

I have tried to change many dependencies and many different configuration, but don't know how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the Hibernate 4.3.5 implements the JPA 2.1 standard, while the GlassFish 3 (and maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin) implements only JPA 2.0 and that was the reason of the problem.

GlassFish 4 implements the new JPA 2.1, so if you build the app (.war/.ear file) you can deploy it without a problem on the GlassFish 4. But the *maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin* does not currently support the new GlassFish 4.

The solution to this problem might be to simply degrade the Hibernate version to *4.2.15.Final*, that uses the JPA 2.0:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can try to configure your *glassfish-plugin* as mentioned [HERE](https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/glassfish_4_beta_and_maven):

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.2.2</version>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.main</groupId>
       <artifactId>simple-glassfish-api</artifactId>
       <version>4.0-b79</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
       <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
       <version>4.0-b83</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```